# How to change background color programatically without afftecting border?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-color

I would like to create a square with rounded corners and add a background color inside the shape and give it a border color like the following image:

[image: Expected design]

But i am only able to achieve this:

[image: Result]

I have a list of colors that need to be added for each of the rounded square boxes and its dynamic data so any number of colors will be captured from API and shown on the recyclerview. But when i change the background or background color of the layout , the color appears and the background border disappears.

Here is my code for the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/colorframe"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:background="@drawable/status_color_white_square"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:onClick="@{()->viewModel.onItemClick()}">


            <com.monstarlab.instantmac.ui.custom.IMTextView
                android:id="@+id/captionET"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="A"
                android:visibility="@{safeUnbox(viewModel.isSelected ? View.VISIBLE:View.GONE )}" />

        </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The drawable with border:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="6dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="6dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="6dp"
    android:topRightRadius="6dp"/>

<stroke android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#e8e9ea"/>
```

Java Code in adapter viewholder onBind() method:

```
        final StatusColor color = colorlist.get(position);

        statusColorViewModel = new StatusColorViewModel(color, this);

        mBinding.setViewModel(statusColorViewModel);

        mBinding.colorframe.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, color.getColor()));
```

How can I achieve the color change without affecting the border?

Comment: You can create another `drawable` file ?

Comment: @CagriYalcin could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Code:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#000000" />//corner color
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"

        />

    <solid android:color="#8058595b" />// inside Color 

</shape>
```

**Change Above solid color dynamically:**

```
GradientDrawable bgShape = (GradientDrawable)btn.getBackground();
bgShape.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

**For Stroke use below:**

```
GradientDrawable myGrad = (GradientDrawable)rectangle.getBackground();
myGrad.setStroke(2, Color.RED);
```

Comment: Lodi : Thanks for that. But I will be changing the color dynamically. So will it make sense to add the <solid android:color="#8058595b" /> line?

Comment: In addition to this answer, u will have to change this drawable at runtime, just create the same drawable with deferent solid color

Comment: i am sorry but this doesn't work with my custom colors. I tried them with the following colors : #343434 , #d3bbe8

Answer (score 0):

hi bro following this code

1 : code for the xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/status_color_white_square">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/colorframe"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/captionET"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="A" />

        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

2 : The drawable:
  I)  bg.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="6dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="6dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="6dp"
        android:topRightRadius="6dp" />

    <solid android:color="#cf0000"/>

</shape>
```

II)  bg.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="6dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="6dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="6dp"
        android:topRightRadius="6dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#e8e9ea" />
</shape>
```

3: Java Code

```
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class Temp extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.temp);


        FrameLayout colorframe = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.colorframe);



        ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(
                colorframe,
                ColorStateList.valueOf(/*dynamic color enter here*/getResources().getColor(R.color.green)));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks deep. But its not working. I am getting a blue applied onto the drawable

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved by creating a relative layout and text view in it by placing the text in center. Apply the background property for layout by using drawable resource file.

main_activity.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#3F51B5">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Google"
            android:id="@+id/txt_google"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

Create drawable resource border.xml and put the below shape and stoke properties



   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <corners android:bottomRightRadius="6dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="6dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="6dp"
            android:topRightRadius="6dp"/>
        <solid
            android:color="@android:color/darker_gray">
        </solid>
        <stroke android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/colorAccent"/></shape>
```